# Unable to read properly from messages.properties

Tags: spring-mvc

The deployment folder structure is given in this image.

http://i41.tinypic.com/25fpvsh.jpg

and my configuration file is given below

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
  <property name="basenames">
    <list>
      <value>messages</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

My problem is when I used the tag `<spring:message code = "something">`
I get an exception `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code  for locale 'en_US'` when I try to access Login.jsp.

But when I place the same file(Login.jsp) in the WEB-INF\jsp folder, I am not getting any errors and the values present in messages_en.properties is retrieved and displayed in the webpage. Can anyone tell me the reason why this is happening and provide a solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

`login.jsp` (and the .properties files) should be **in** the WEB-INF directory. Then change the messageSource bean declaration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is working fine when I move the .jsp files inside the WEB-INF folder.